# Scale animation in front?

Tags: android, animation, layout

I'm applying a scale animation to a view (a grid item), which is in a gridview, which is in a pager, which is in a linear layout.

Everything already works besides my scaled griditem becomes larger than the gridview / pager, and it's clipped (or hidden? by siblings of the pager). I tried putting `android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"` everywhere where there's a parent view and it's supported (in the linear layout and in the grid view), but had no effect.

I also tried calling bringToFront() on the pager, but this also doesn't work, still get clipped and besides of that causes repositions the pager at the bottom of the layout, which is unwanted.

How do I play the animation in front of everything?

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution? Haven't solved this in a whole year...

Comment: I "solved" this using a scale animation for the complete activity, which was acceptable for my case. Other than that, I can think only of creating a overlay-layout on top of everything (Relative or FrameLayout), replicate the item there and apply the animation to it.

Comment: Thanks for the info; that's what I figured I was going to have to do, but it's so much more of a hack than a solution that I thought there had to be a better way to do it. Especially when everyone keeps saying setClipChildren should solve the problem (when it doesn't...). Thanks!